# How do i remove all Dojo widgets with id starts with xyz

Tags: dojo, widget, destroy

I have scrollableViews with a id name like `idname1`, `idname2`, `idname88` etc.  I want to destroy all widgets with a id name starting with "idname".

I have tried this:

```
var widgets = dijit.findWidgets("id^=divNodes");
dojo.forEach(widgets, function(w) {
w.destroyRecursive(false);
```

It seems that I cant use `dijit.findWidgets("id^=divNodes")` for this.

What will work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs...

> registry.findWidgets returns an array of all non-nested widgets inside
>   the given DOM node.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/registry.html

You could iterate over the registry yourself

```
require(["dojo/_base/array", "dijit/registry"], function(array, registry){
    var startsWith = function(wholeString, lookFor) {
        return wholeString.slice(0, lookFor.length) == lookFor}
    };

    var toDestroy = array.filter(registry.toArray(), 
        function(w) { return startsWith(w.id, 'divNodes'); });

    array.forEach(toDestroy, function(w) { w.destroyRecursive(false); });
});
```

Comment: However, if you have nested widgets, you should filter the whole collection of widgets, which you can obtain from registry.toArray()

Comment: That is what I used in the code above.  Are you saying it should be different?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad... I was looking at the registry.findWidgets in the "From the docs part"... next time I'll read till the end :-)

Comment: No worries.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't given wrong advice.